# What is the security vulnerability of Drupal and a HTML site?

Tags: html, security, drupal

Suppose a Drupal site is on a https server like for example:

http://example.com/

And then I create a sub folder on the server like:

http://example.com/myfolder

...and I put a HTML site inside of the "myfolder."  Is the Drupal site and this "myfolder" HTML site still secure?  Or is there now a security issue?

Comment: "Secure" in what way? If you mean TLS, the certificate covers the domain, so nothing's changed in that respsect

Comment: By "secure" I mean do the HTML pages in the sub folder make the Drupal site more vulnerable to attack?  I'm trying to convince colleagues to let me build small HTML sites in sub folders but they're saying it will mess up the site's security and make it more vulnerable.  I disagree with them but I'm not an expert with security so that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I don't see how it would compromise the site, but it is probably a good idea to ask for their specific concerns. They may have their reasons, based on the environment. Could you give us a little more information about the use case here? There may be better more "Drupalish" ways to solve the problem and keep your admins happy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This is .gov site.  They have Drupal installed as the main CMS.  But there are other, more creative, ways to create multimedia sites to accompany the main site.  The creative multimedia sites will function with HTML, CSS, and JS.  All of the sites - the main Drupal one and the multimedia ones - will reside on the same server with the "https" URL.  I understand their concern about security and keeping the site secure and protected.  But at the same time, I don't see why or how the multimedia sites would affect negatively the security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me reference your comment on this question:

> By "secure" I mean do the HTML pages in the sub folder make the Drupal
>   site more vulnerable to attack? I'm trying to convince colleagues to
>   let me build small HTML sites in sub folders but they're saying it
>   will mess up the site's security and make it more vulnerable. I
>   disagree with them but I'm not an expert with security so that's why
>   I'm asking this question.

Short answer, no. Just make sure [directory browsing is disabled](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml) and if you do put any dynamic content in the subdirectory [make sure it is secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10).

Consider placing a Web Application Firewall in front of your webserver for an additional level of security.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This is .gov site.  They have Drupal installed as the main CMS.  But there are other, more creative, ways to create multimedia sites to accompany the main site.  The creative multimedia sites will function with HTML, CSS, and JS.  All of the sites - the main Drupal one and the multimedia ones - will reside on the same server with the "https" URL.  I understand their concern about security and keeping the site secure and protected.  But at the same time, I don't see why or how the multimedia sites would affect negatively the security.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; it should be completely fine. Maybe they need some more security training to know exactly where and when you can find vulnerabilities? Could you close this question by clicking the empty tick under the vote buttons? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Additional to mjsa's answer I would like to add that your colleagues have to trust **you**, because when you are allowed to add files freely to a drupal site it would be easy for you to **gain admin rights to the drupal site**. So maybe that's their concern because you and your colleagues only have the right to edit the contents of your drupal site and not to administrate it?

Comment: I helped build the Drupal site so I already have admin privileges.  I also have admin on a WordPress site. These multimedia sites are not Drupal either.  Drupal is their CMS platform but the multimedia sites are creative interactive sites, ones you can't build with Drupal.  What they're really afraid of is trying something new, something different.  And when it's something they don't understand, they immediately throw up roadblocks to "progress."  I've been working in multimedia design for 27 years and I've seen it over and over again throughout my career.  It's no different here.